# upgrade to install postgis with postgres-9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have `postgresql-9.4` and `potsgresql-contrib` installed and am trying to add the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

But I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgis : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going 
 to be installed postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0)
```

But it is not going to be installed

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyone've been there?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear here. Did you fix `libgdal1`?

Comment: sorry @tadman, im not wise in the subject. How do i "fix" it?

Comment: You could try installing it manually.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Now that did not work because it depends on a whole bunch of "not installable" packs. Do you happen to know the library?

Comment: I've installed PostGIS on Fedora successfully, and it should work on Debian or Ubuntu just the same unless your distribution is broken. This really isn't a question for Stack Overflow, though. You might want to take it up with the PostGIS team directly or the maintainer of the PostGIS port for your Linux distribution.

Comment: Consider [following these instructions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt), which has [a compatible version of libgdal](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/g/gdal/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but you should try to install [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/). GDAL is a library for geospatial datatypes. It is available as package for many distributions. If it is not available for your distri., you can always install GDAL via manual [source-code](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints) compilation.